# Update latest spend on Google Sheets based on Date dimension

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet report -- used to monitor our marketing campaign reports. So my goal here is to be able to update a cell showing the our current spending as of yesterday.

How can I go about doing this? Please advise.

Sample data would look like:

```
Date | Cost |

01/01 | 2.50 |

02/01 | 3.50 |
```

I want the cell to update daily with the latest cost data. Is this possible? Using what formula.

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [SUMIF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) function. [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10A1yUWbX-aGpRP8nWEKBe84FAvJi9D58174mG4ESnUU)